# Várias consultas e depois ordenar esses resultados de forma que apareçam em order por data

Tags: php, mysqli

Preciso fazer *N* consultas de acordo com um valor recebido de outra consulta.

```
$idList = array();
if (@$_GET["page"] == "profile"){
    $idList[0] = $_GET['pid'];
    $cont = 0;
}
else {
    $idList[0] = $uid;
    $cont = 1;
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `friends_list` WHERE user_id = '$uid'");
    while($friends = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
        $idList[$cont] = $friends['friend_id'];
        $cont++;
    }

    $cont = count($idList);
    $cont--;
}


$pos = 1;
while($cont>= 0){
    $id = $idList[$cont];
    $query2 = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `post` WHERE user_id = $id'");
    while($posts = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query2)){
        $pList[$pos] = $posts; 
        $pos++;
    }
    $cont--;
}
$cont = 1;

foreach($pList as $post){

    $id = $post['user_id']; 
    $query3 = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `profile` WHERE id = '$id' LIMIT 1") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    $owner = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query3);
```

No caso, armazenei os resultados em um vetor, mas não sei se é a melhor forma de se fazer. Detalhe, não faço ideia de como organizar o vetor de forma eficaz pois a quantidade de resultados pode ser muito grande.

Qual a melhor maneira de fazer essa busca? Através de vetor ou existe outra forma de obter e organizar os dados?

E se caso seja vetor, alguma sugestão de como organizar por data?

Obrigado.

Comment: Você quer organizar a consulta por data, certo? Por que não usa o `order by <nome_da_coluna_que_armazena_a_data` ?

Comment: Exato, mas são vários users_ids diferentes com múltiplas possibilidades pra cada um.

Ou seja:

user_id = 1, data 27/09/2018
user_id = 1, data 25/09/2018
user_id = 3, data 1/10/2018
user_id = 4, data 30/09/2018

Comment: Então tenho que intercalar esses user_ids ordenado pela data.

Comment: Tem que ordenar por data, mas os `user_id`'s tem que ficar todos juntos? Isso?

Comment: Não, os ids aparecem na ordem da data. Estilo postagens de redes sociais para mostrar as postagens de amigos e a do próprio usuário de acordo com a data de publicação.

Comment: você quer então carregar uma 'timeline'?, Com postagens ordenadas por data? Mas nesse caso, pra quê você precisa dos `user_id`s? Acho que estou entendendo, mas gostaria que desse mais alguns detalhes

Comment: Exato. Eu preciso da user_id pra controlar quem é amigo de quem, entende? Ele vai buscar as postagens de amigos somente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você não consegue minimizar o uso de tantos laços juntando todas as querys em uma só?

**Por exemplo:** *(sql atualizado para listar os posts do usuário também)*

```
"SELECT * FROM `friend_list` AS `fl`
INNER JOIN `post` AS `p` ON `p`.`user_id` = `fl`.`friend_id` or `p`.`user_id` = `fl`.`user_id`
INNER JOIN `profile` AS `prof` ON `prof`.`id` = `p`.`user_id`
WHERE `fl`.`user_id` = '{$id}'
ORDER BY `p`.`data` DESC"
```

Não tem problema você juntar e concatenar tudo dentro de um vetor, só tome cuidado com a performance caso você tenha muitos itens para listar.

O mais correto, caso haja muitos itens, é criar uma paginação para exibir apenas "x" itens por página (alguns frameworks fazem isso bem fácil).
Ou, como em uma timeline, carregar apenas "x" itens conforme o usuário rolar a página para baixo e não carregar tudo de uma vez.

Se optar por fazer tudo nesta única query (com inner joins), tome cuidado com o nome das colunas em cada tabela, caso haja nomes repetidos pode causar algum comportamento inesperado.

Caso queria continuar usando o mesmo método de vários loops, acredito que um order by na tabela de post já resolva o seu problema:

```
$query2 = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `post` WHERE user_id = $id' ORDER BY `data` desc");
```

Outra forma de organizar o vetor também seria usando o "**array_map**" nativo do PHP.

Comment: Opa... Era bem isso que eu precisava! Muito obrigado pela ajuda! 

Com essa consulta, não preciso armazenar em vetor :)
Sim, eu pretendo não carregar tudo de uma vez.

Só um probleminha, na timeline eu preciso que mostre também os posts do usuário também. Tentei usar no where ...WHERE `fl`.`user_id` = '{$pid}' OR `p`.`user_id` = '{$pid}'  ORDER BY `p`.`date` DESC"); mas carrega 3x cada post :P

Comment: eu criei um novo registro pra cada usuário, onde diz que é amigo de si mesmo.
Não sei se é a melhor maneira, mas funcionou! :P

Comment: @Marciohrm atualizei o sql da resposta, agora deve listar os posts do usuário também. Se puder, marca a resposta como correta para poder ajudar outros usuários com a mesma dúvida futuramente :)

Comment: Opa, de fato funcionou! O único problema é que está retornando 3x a mesma publicação do usuário logado. Vou tentar descobrir como arrumar, se não der certo, vou deixar como tinha feito antes de tu mudar o código!

Muito obrigado pela ajuda! (: